# How to validate that object key's value should present in another object using Joi?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, joi

I am using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) for object dalidation.
suppose my objects are

```
global_object = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Alok"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Ajay"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Ankit"},
]

// valid object because id is present in global_object
object1 = {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "India"
}

// invalid object because id is not present in global_object
object2 = {
    "id": 7,
    "country": "India"
}
```

I want to add validation to this `object1` and `object2` that value of `id` should be present in `global_object` using `joi`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be possible using [Joi.any().valid()](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.7#anyvalidvalues---aliases-equal)

```
var schema = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.any().valid(...global_object.map(e=>e['id'])),
    country: Joi.string()
})

console.log(schema.validate(object1)) // valid case
console.log(schema.validate(object2)) // this will show error as its invalid
```

Here are output

```
> console.log(schema.validate(object1))
{ value: { id: 2, country: 'India' } }
undefined
> console.log(schema.validate(object2))
{ value: { id: 7, country: 'India' },
  error:
   { ValidationError: "id" must be one of [1, 2, 3]
     _original: { id: 7, country: 'India' },
     details: [ [Object] ] } }
undefined
>
```